# Sub class of Parent class using @RequiredArgsConstructor Lombok is not finding default constructor in Parent class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I'm working on a Spring project with Lombok plugin. I added `@RequiredArgsConstructor` annotation and made the parent class's fields `final` to initialize it using either `@AllArgsConstructor` or `@RequiredArgsConstructor` instead of field injection (using `@Autowired` for class fields).
However, for some reason, the subclass **DraftsPostMethod** is reporting a message that *there's no default constructor found* in the parent class **AbstractContributoryServiceMethod**

I'm not sure what's causing it because I did the same (added the annotation) on other classes to initialize them Lombok way.

The subclass reports an error that reads "*There is no default constructor available in ... AbstractContributoryServiceMethod*"

**Subclass:**

```
@Service
public class DraftsPostMethod extends AbstractContributoryServiceMethod<DraftManagementRequest, 
    BasicServiceModel<DraftManagementRequest>,
    BasicServiceResponse<Void>> {
    
    private final Validator<DraftManagementRequest> validator = new Validator<DraftManagementRequest>(){
        @Nonnull
        @Override
        public ValidationState validate(DraftManagementRequest draftManagementRequest){
            return ValidationState.commence();
        }
    };
    
    private final DraftService draftService;
    
    @Autowired
    public DraftsPostMethod(DraftService draftService){ // getting the red line error here
        this.draftService = draftService;
    }
    //...and so on...
}
```

**Parent class :**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractContributoryServiceMethod {
    protected final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    
    private final ExceptionManager exceptionManager; //this line was @Autowired private ExceptionManager exceptionManager
    private final ValidationErrorTranslator validationErrirTranslator; //this line was @Autowired private ValidationErrorTranslator validationErrirTranslator
    private final ExceptionDetailsLogger exceptionDetailsLogger; //this line was @Autowired private ExceptionDetailsLogger exceptionDetailsLogger
    
    //... and so on...
}
```

I'd appreciate any comments or answers. Thank you.

Comment: `@RequiredArgsConstructor` generates a constructor with all fields that have been marked as `final`. That's why you don't have a default constructor. You can add a no args constructor by yourself or using lombok

Comment: I thought adding a no args constructor might not initialize the `final` fields

Comment: You will be "forced" to initialize them because they have no value.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok's @NoArgsConstructor annotation will generate the default constructor it is looking for.

https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll have to initialize the fields using this approach?

Comment: Correct. @NoArgsConstructor will create the class object with default - null fields, so you will have to set them.